What's writing "onChange started" and "onChange completed" to the console in Angular/Bootstrap?
I've just added a select element to an Angular component and, when the component is loaded in the browser and I select a value from the list, the following messages are being written to the console:
onChange started
onChange completed

These aren't coming from my application. Is this a bit of debugging code that got left behind in either my current version of Angular (17.1.1) or Bootstrap (5.3.3)?

"These aren't coming from my application" how are you so sure about that? What is the stack trace of these log entries?

Because a search of the application turns up no instances of "onChange started" or "onChange completed".

That says nothing. You can easily print these messages without one of the exact strings being present in the app. One reliable proof would be to see the stack trace which points to one of the packages.

@GreenGrassoHolm issue not reproducible stackblitz

@NarenMurali that Stackblitz uses different versions of Angular, but also with the exact versions it's not reproducible: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-fedtpl

How about this: the only three uses of console in my application are to log the error if there's an error when the standalone application bootstraps the app component; console.log('reloaded'); and console.log('hello').

How do you see a stack trace of a log entry? The messages are in my console (in Chrome on Windows). They're just text, there's no widget for expanding to show a stack trace.

possible that's coming from a dependency?  If you include the code for the select it may help.  (Is it just ? Or is it a custom-tag there?)

I don't know why I hadn't simply looked on the right side of my Chrome console before before but the messages were coming from ContentScript.js:6. I clicked that and the file that opened was shown in the Sources window as being located under "Symantec Extension". So whatever it is, that's the source, and I know I can't do anything about it since the extension is added by organizational policy. Sorry for being a little slow on the uptake, thanks for everyone's contributions.
